# Naive question about 3 sets intersection point

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, inclusion-exclusion

I have three intersecting in at least one point sets $A$, $B$, $C$ with arbitary finite countable cardinality.

The known facts are:

$$
|A|, |B|, |C|
$$
$$
|A \cap B|
$$
$$
|B \cap C|
$$
$$
|C \cap A|
$$

Is it possible to get $|A \cap B \cap C|$ from this knowledge?

Thank you, and have a nice day!

Comment: No. Try some simple examples. You are not adequately specifying the overlaps. If the cardinalities are infinite, then you have an additonal difficulty.

Comment: Thank you! They are finite.

Comment: Then please change the first line to arbitrary *finite* cardinality. "countable" means finite or countably infinite.

Comment: You completely right, i've mixed two problems in one. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inclusion exclusion principle gives you the answer: $$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|B\cap C|-|A\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|.$$
Since you have two unknown elements, you can't conclude.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm not quite sure. I don't know $|A \cup B \cup C|$ as well as $|A \cap B \cap C|$. If i get cardinality for one of them - the problem is solved.

Comment: exactly ! $\ \ \ \ $